How to Increase Bevel Segments in Blender Using a Touchpad?
Hello Blender Community,
I am currently learning Blender using Blender Guru's donut tutorial, and I've encountered an issue while trying to increase the bevel segments of a cylinder without a mouse. In the tutorial, the instructor uses the scroll wheel to add more segments, but I am using a laptop touchpad. For more information, I'm using Blender 4.1.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Manual Workarounds:
Attempted to use keyboard shortcuts, but couldn’t find a suitable alternative for scrolling.
Tried to use AutoHotkey to simulate mouse scrolls, but it didn’t work as expected.
Changing Input Settings:
I looked into changing the keymap settings in Blender but couldn't figure out how to map the scrolling function to keyboard shortcuts effectively.
I’m looking for:

Any built-in Blender shortcuts or settings that can help increase bevel segments without a mouse.
Recommendations for add-ons that could provide this functionality.
Advice from users who have faced and solved similar issues with touchpad use in Blender.
Thank you for your assistance!


The shortcuts for the number of segments of the bevel operation are Numpad+ and Numpad-. You can change them in the settings 3D View > Bevel Modal Map > Increase Segments and ... > Decrease Segments. The shortcuts to change the size of the "circle" of Proportional Editing are Page Up and Page Down. For scrolling and zooming, try to use 2 fingers on the touchpad and do a zoom-in/zoom-out gesture. (doesn't work on every touchpad)

Look into Emulate Numpad/3ButtonMouse functionality which comes with Blender.
